# Is it possible to inherit from boost::function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost

I'd like to know if it's possible to inherit from boost::function.

Basically, for ease of use, what I'd like to 
is have a type "Delegate" which is basically a boost::function.
 It's just for ease of use in some code I'm writing.

I at one point typedef'd boost::function to Delegate, but typedef'ing in my experience plays hell with gdb stuff. Especially if it's templated, so I wanted to avoid that (ever try debugging stl containers that've been typdeffed? oofta).

I found some code online which gave some sort of an example:

```
template<class Signature>
class Delegate : public boost::function<Signature>
{
public: 
    using boost::function<Signature>::operator();
};
```

Now, as I attempt to use it I get some errors.
A usage example would be:

```
Tank * tankptr = new Tank();
Delegate<void ()> tankShoot(boost::bind(boost::mem_fn(&Tank::Shoot),tankptr));
```

This yields errors such as

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Delegate<void ()()>::Delegate(boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, Tank>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<Tank*> > >)’
Delegate.h:26: note: candidates are: Delegate<void ()()>::Delegate()
Delegate.h:26: note:                 Delegate<void ()()>::Delegate(const Delegate<void()()>&)
```

If I had to guess why I'm getting these errors, I'd have to say it's cause I'm missing
some kind of copy constructor that takes whatever base a boost::bind constructor returns.

Any thoughts on how I can get past this hurdle, or anyone able to point me to good examples
of inheriting from boost::function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deriving from a class does not automatically 'inherit' the base class constructors for the derived class. You will need to create all required constructors there.

Comment: I was just getting at posting a similar answer. He's going to need a constructor that takes boost::function<> and passes it to the base class.

Comment: I figured as much. Any examples of this being done that anyone knows of? I'm having trouble with the syntax and would benefit from a good example.

Comment: Ah, I think I figured it out. I had to do something like
`template<class Signature>
class Delegate : public boost::function<Signature>

{

public:

    using boost::function<Signature>::operator();

    Delegate() : boost::function<Signature>() {}
    Delegate(const boost::function<Signature>& x) : boost::function<Signature>(x) {}
    
};
`
(My formatting is terrible, apologies).

Comment: @sbrett: You could also just implement a template ctor `template<class Functor> Delegate(Functor f) : boost::function<Signature>(f){}` and rely on the Boost.Function ctors.

Answer (score 0):

hKaiser was correct in my needing to write the required constructors.

I had a hell of a time of it, until I found the interface file for the boost class "function"
on their website.

In the end I ended up with something like:

```
template<class Signature>
class Delegate : public boost::function<Signature>
{
public:
  ///use the functor operator from the original class
  using boost::function<Signature>::operator();

  ///base constructor for our new type, 
  Delegate() : boost::function<Signature>() {/*empty*/}

  ///copy constructor for our new type
  Delegate(const boost::function<Signature>& x) : boost::function<Signature>(x) {/*empty*/}

  Delegate& operator=(const Delegate & _delegate)
  {
    boost::function<Signature> x = _delegate;
    try
    {
      dynamic_cast<boost::function<Signature> & >(*this) = x;
    }
    catch(bad_cast &bc)
    {
      cout << "Bad Cast Exception. " << bc.what();
      int * ptr = NULL;
      *ptr = 1; //force seg fault instead of assert
    }
    return *this;
  }
};
```

I'm not sure if I'm properly using the dynamic_cast (in the context of adhering to good coding practices) or if I even need it there in the assignment operator, but it does work, and works extremely well.

Comment: Wanted to add a bit more to this,Acutally, although the above works on compiler gcc 4.1.1